# obtain Angular CLI versions

Tags: angular, eclipse

I am trying to create a angular project using Angular IDE in eclipse photon. But getting error when i click on new Angular project. [image]

when i execute the ng --version in my command prompt im getting below

```
 _                      _                 ____ _     ___
/ \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
```

/ △ \ | '_ \ / _`| | | | |/ _` | '**|   | |   | |    | |
  /**  \| | | | (| | |*| | | (*| | |      | |***| |*** | |
 /*/   __| |*|__, |__,*|*|__,*|*|       ____|_____|***|
                |***/

```
Angular CLI: 7.2.1
Node: 10.15.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------

@angular-devkit/architect    0.12.1
@angular-devkit/core         7.2.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.2.1
@schematics/angular          7.2.1
@schematics/update           0.12.1
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript
```

do i need to do some setting in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything about angular cli seems ok.
I cant see typescript version in your result.

check it with this:

```
tsc --version
```

Comment: if you did, you must install typescript by `npm install -g typescript`

Comment: there was some problem with my ide. i installed it as standalone again n not as eclipse plug in, started working for me. Thanks for your time.

Comment: your welcome, anyway you need nodejs,typescript and cli installed to go

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the wizard may be having trouble locating a list of Angular CLI releases, which may be because you need to set up your proxy via Window>Preferences>General>Network Connections (you only need to set HTTP or HTTPS depending on which of these is needed to connect to your proxy). Internet connection is generally needed for much of the Angular tooling. Each project can specify the level of Angular CLI, node and npm, the releases for these are downloaded as required (each release of node and npm is only downloaded once).

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I downloaded the Spring Tool Suite plugin in Eclipse and tried to install the Angular IDE Plugin on top of it.
There are 2 fixes/workarounds that did the trick for me:

1) I restarted eclipse with "Run as Administrator". There seemed to be a network connection issue with Angular CLI which got resolved after running as administrator.

2) Download the Spring Tool Suite IDE separately,install the Angular IDE Plugin inside it and allowed network permission (during the launch) and it worked!