# An internal error occurred during: "Obtain Angular CLI versions"

Tags: angular, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, command-line-interface

Whenever I try to create a new angular project in eclipse photon I get this error. 
Whereas I have installed node.js and related modules.

Does anyone know what wrong I'm doing?

Eclipse error
[image]

Installed node.js in the system
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Does anything in this help? https://debugmode.net/2017/06/22/how-to-upgrade-to-latest-angular-cli/ This also appears similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193720/obtain-angular-cli-versions Particulary this comment... there was some problem with my ide. i installed it as standalone again not as eclipse plug in, started working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you are using a proxy to reach the Internet but haven't defined it correctly (or at all) in eclipse. You need to define it based on how you connect to the proxy, so probably only need to set one of HTTP, HTTPS or SOCKS. If you have unneeded settings, clear those that aren't needed (select the line then click the Clear button).

Comment: Eclipse updates and maven repos all get downloaded easily. I even have set the proxy in general tab of preference.

Comment: Ensure you can get to https://registry.npmjs.org/ which is used to obtain the list of versions.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you just try that URL in an eclipse internal web browser to, hopefully, ensure that the eclipse defined proxy is used. If that doesn't tell us anything, check the eclipse error log for errors that occured at the same time as the error you mentioned.

Comment: Your solution worked, turns out that my office firewall was blocking the request.